# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class z.y.x.u.SimpleCompileTest can not access a member of class MyClass with modifiers ""

Tags: java, reflection

While using the reflection API i'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class z.y.x.u.SimpleCompileTest can not access a member of class MyClass with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at z.y.x.u.SimpleCompileTest.reflectionCall(SimpleCompileTest.java:44)
    at z.y.x.f.RunFunctionality.doPost(RunFunctionality.java:116)
    at z.y.x.f.RunFunctionality.doGet(RunFunctionality.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

this is my Psedu Code

```
public static void reflectionCall() {
        ClassLoader classLoader  =  SimpleCompileTest.class.getClassLoader();
        try{
             Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("MyClass");

             Object t = aClass.newInstance();

             System.out.println("aClass.getName() = " + aClass.getName());
             Method  method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod ("myMethod", null);
             method.setAccessible(true);
             method.invoke(t, null);
.....
}
```

it's throwing the error when the following error is happening

```
Object t = aClass.newInstance();
```

The MyClass.class file is in jar file, which is being added dynamically in the class path while execution the content of MyClass.java is

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("My Method Called");
    }

}
```

Not able to figure out, what is the Problem any help more appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's what the class is? It seems (from the error) like the constructor has default visibility, ie. no access modifier.

Answer (score 7):

The exception message is

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class z.y.x.u.SimpleCompileTest can not access a member of class MyClass with modifiers “”
```

Note the lack of modifier value inside the `""`. The javadoc of `Class#newInstance()` states

> Throws:
>
> **IllegalAccessException** - if the class or its nullary constructor **is not accessible**.

In other words, your `MyClass` constructor is not accessible. From your code it seems to be, but I'm going to guess you copy pasted it wrong. It's most probably missing the `public` modifier, ie. it has default accessibility. Since that class and your `SimpleCompileTest` class are in different packages, the constructor is not visible.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue with Spring Boot, with slightly different message, but the solution from @sotirios-delimanolis helped:

```
Class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor can not access a 
member of class com.etc.bla.model.entity.BackendBaseEntity with modifiers "public"
```

The `BackendBaseEntity` class had indeed package visibility, and making it `public` solved the error.